# Jetty Server - how to handle a GET request with parameters?

Tags: java, http, servlets, get, jetty

This must be awfully simple, but I didn't find an answer.

[Here](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Tutorial/Embedding_Jetty#Hello_World_Handler) is an easy example on how to listen to a get request with a jetty server.

However, it doesn't cover the case that it's not just a "http://www.foo.com/bar" request, but something like "http://www.foo.com/bar?name=guy&value=1".

So how do I get the parameters in jetty?

Comment: This question isn't specific to Jetty, it relates to the Java Servlet Specification / API.

Comment: Ah, thank you. That helps where to look for answers. :-)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[This is the API for ServletRequest](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameter%28java.lang.String%29). You should use:

```
request.getParameter("name");
request.getParameter("value");
```

Answer (score 6):

```
request.getParameter("name");
request.getParameter("value");
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use request.getParameter("name") and request.getParameter("value") in the doGet method of your servlet.